# Laravel under a load balancer + centralized redis session server

Tags: php, laravel, redis, load-balancing, horizontal-scaling

I have 2 laravel nodes running in separate servers under a load balancer, and a dedicated redis server for session and cache storage.

I configured the session and cache drivers accordingly to "redis" and it connects just fine. I see files being stored inside the redis server.

The issue is when I try to login, the page just gets refreshed without printing the "Invalid credential" errors that are normally stored in session.

Since the load balancer keeps redirecting from one node to another, the session is somehow getting lost. As a single instance it works just fine though. Is there anyone having the same issue with laravel and load balancing?

If there is a possible fix without configuring the balancer to use sticky sessions, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this package [TrustedProxy](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) solves your issue. Install it and then just add it to `config/trustedproxy.php`:

```
return [
'proxies' => [
    '192.168.10.10',
],

// These are defaults already set in the config:
'headers' => [
    (defined('Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED') ? Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_FORWARDED : 'forwarded') => 'FORWARDED',
    \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_IP    => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST  => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
    \Illuminate\Http\Request::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT  => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
]
];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!